# Privilege Description for Moderator Tools should be changed

Tags: bug, status-completed

Right now the description text for the "access to moderation tools" privilege says, in part:

> You have earned the highest level of privilege in our community

With the addition of the "trusted user" level it seems like this is incorrect and should be changed.

Comment: May I ask how did you know this as your score is below this level?

Comment: Exactly what do you think needs changing and why? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: @Khaled: On the Privileges Page (click on the number next to your name on the main SO), you can click on any of the privileges, whether you have it or not, to see what it is all about.

Comment: @John, if you do what I just showed Khaled, and click on the "Access to Mod Tools" Privilege, the description that you will see will say the line I quoted. Because the additional levels have been added, the part I quoted is no longer factual...

Comment: @BenGC, now it makes sense. I suppose this is the new thing I learn today. ;)

Comment: Not seeing it now, maybe they fixed it but forgot to tag this question.

Answer (score 2):

This has apparently been fixed.